# jQuery toLocaleString on numbers in a text string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to use `toLocaleString` to change my number from 10000 to 10,000 which is simple by using:

```
var numberString = 10000;

console.log(numberString .toLocaleString("en"));
```

By how can I make it so number which are in a text string use the same format?

```
var numberString = 'The amount is 10000';

console.log(numberString.toLocaleString("en"));
```

So it should be 'The amount is 10,000'.

Comment: `numberString.replace(/\b\d+\b/,n=>n.toLocaleString("en"))`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think you mean `numberString.replace(/\d+/, n => parseFloat(n).toLocaleString("en"))`

Comment: Yes. Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to search for number in the string with `g` flag to replace the number anywhere in the string with the formatted one. Also, we need to convert the found matches to a `Number` first, as they are strings actually and [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) method only works on a number.

```js
var numberString = 'The amount is 10000. But can be also 2000000';
var formatted = numberString.replace(/\d+/g, n => Number(n).toLocaleString("en"))
console.log(formatted);
```

For debugging purpose, if you want to see what substrings are matched in the replacement function of `.replace()` method you can do it like:

```js
var numberString = 'The amount is 10000. But can be also 2000000 or more 5000.';
numberString.replace(/\d+/g, n => console.log(n, typeof n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numberString = $('.numbers').text();
var formatted = numberString.replace(/\d+/g, n => Number(n).toLocaleString())
$('.numbers').html(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="numbers">455556998</span>
```